# POST Error 500 Internal Application Error Xray

Tags: api, postman, x-ray

I am trying to import my cucumber test cases to Xray using postman but i receiving the error message:
`{
    "error": "Internal Application Error!"
}`

I am using postman to do integration with Xray, I already can do a GET to get the test results, I can do a POST to update the status test case. I am trying now to import my cucumber test to Xray, I am sending in my request https://xray.cloud.xpand-it.com/api/v1/import/feature?projectKey=XXX and I am adding the file with .feature with my cucumber test, but when I click on Send I getting this response message: 
`{
    "error": "Internal Application Error!"
}`

Isn't a connection\autentication problem because I can do the other tasks that I mentioned. When I try without a file I got the message that is necessary a file, so I imagine that is a problem to read the file, but I am using the template of Xray documentation https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/XRAYCLOUD/Importing+Cucumber+Tests+-+REST
and I am sending the file as multipart/form-data

Someone knows how can I solve this?

Thanks

`Params= projectKey XXX
Authentication = Bearer Token correctly token
Headers= Content-Type, application/json
Body = form-data, file, .feature file with cucumber test`

Answer (score 1):

With support from Xray team, the problem was solved, I was choosing the file but not typing file in the key, this solved
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYLOr.png